# How to abbreviate IEEE conference names

Tags: ieee-style

Per IEEE guideline, the conferences and journal names in references should be abbreviated. The file IEEEabrv.bib contains the IEEE journal names with their corresponding abbrv. How do I abbreviate the conference names? Is there a similar file available?

Comment: See http://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/IEEE-Editorial-Style-Manual-for-Authors.pdf,   Appendix **F**

Answer (score 1):

Beside the bib file 'IEEEabrv.bib' provided by IEEE for abbreviating IEEE journal names, there is also a bib file 'abbrev.bib' for ACM journals where you can download [here](https://portalparts.acm.org/hippo/latex_templates/acmart-primary.zip).

There is also a list of USEFUL ABBREVIATIONS IN REFERENCES in Section IV of this [guide](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).